# Visual Studio Code not displaying docker files after attaching to a container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to attach visual studio code to a running container, and it does show successfully attached. However it does not show any files in the file explorer

[image: File explorer empty after attaching to a container]

The bash command line also works fine and lists all the files. I wanted to open the files installed on the container in VS code.

Comment: You need to "Open Folder" and select a path to show files in the container.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't show any files

Comment: I am also facing same issue.  How did you fix it? I tried wsl shutdown but no luck

Answer (score 1):

It was a stupid wsl issue.

Running `wsl --shutdown` and `wsl` afterwards fixed the issue for me